# input numpy array to linspace and for loop range problem

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, linspace

I am having trouble trying to use multiple values to test since linspace and range in for loop is not accepting array as an input.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
gp_input = np.array([31,61])

def var_gp(gp):
   for i in gp:
      x_l = np.linspace(0,3,gp)
      ...
   for i in range(gp):
      ...
```

What the error tells me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "variable gp.py", line 306, in 
var_gp(gp_input)

```
File "variable gp.py", line 18, in var_gp
    x_l = np.linspace(0,3,gp)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in linspace
  File "/home/rjomega/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 120, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

It feels like it would become a bad habit if I'll just manually change the value of gp and hoping I can just insert as much values to try. Thank you.

[link to complete code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yikPLIKx0A_TqElui5eznz2SQ9Zf1yFm8N2X52rfi_A/edit?usp=sharing)

it works fine if I will just manually change the value of gp and not using def function

Solution I have found if you also experienced this kind of problem:

```
for i in gp:
       gp = i
          x_l = np.linspace(0,3,gp)
          ...
       for i in range(gp):
          ...
```

adding gp = i seems to bypass the problem

Comment: I can't run your code or know where the error happened. Please see [ask]

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oh Im sorry about that. I thought those parts of my code would suffice. It feels like it would be messy if i copy pasted everything. I placed it in google docs using code blocks. [gdocs link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yikPLIKx0A_TqElui5eznz2SQ9Zf1yFm8N2X52rfi_A/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Showing all of the error would be more useful

Comment: @hpaulj oh ok thanks! will add it

Comment: The third argument to `linspace` is supposed to be one integer.

Comment: @hpaulj is there any alternative I can do to produce two different set of results for the values of gp? (different set of results for gp = 31 and gp = 61). also from what I understand, in the "for i in gp:" part it will only take one value from the numpy array right? so I thought it would work normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `gp` that's an array or list, iterate like this:

```
In [471]: gp = np.array([3,6])
In [472]: for i in gp:
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     xi = np.linspace(0,3,i)
     ...:     print(xi)
     ...: 
3
[0.  1.5 3. ]
6
[0.  0.6 1.2 1.8 2.4 3. ]
```

Note that I use `i` when calling `linspace`, not `gp`.

When we pass the array to `linspace` we get your error:

```
In [473]: np.linspace(0,3,gp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-473-7032efa38f7c>", line 1, in <module>
    np.linspace(0,3,gp)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in linspace
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 120, in linspace
    num = operator.index(num)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

In general in a `for i in gp:` expression, don't use `gp` with the body.  You want to use `i`, the iteration variable.  The whole point to using a `for` loop is to work with the elements of `gp`, not with the whole thing.

We can't use the array in `range` either.  It has to be number elements, one at a time:

```
In [477]: range(gp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-477-4e92b04fe1fc>", line 1, in <module>
    range(gp)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

In [478]: for i in gp:
     ...:     print(list(range(i)))
     ...: 
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution I have found if you also experienced this kind of problem:

```
for i in gp:
       gp = i
       x_l = np.linspace(0,3,gp)
          ...
       for i in range(gp):
          ...
```

adding gp = i seems to bypass the problem